# Setting P3P headers in Apache causes Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, p3p, mod-headers

I wanted to set the P3P Headers by adding them to `.htaccess` using the following:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set P3P "CP="ALL DSP COR CUR ADM TAI OUR IND COM NAV INT""
</IfModule>
```

However, this causes an Internal Server Error. The only related entry in the server log I can find is .htaccess : `Header has too many arguments`

As far as I can tell, `mod_headers.c` loaded.

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Look in the error log to see what the exact error is. Perhaps it's the double double quotes?

Comment: Should that *as* be a *has*?

Comment: I am looking at the Apache error_log in Console (the server runs on OSX), but there is no specific error number, just a generic note. Let me see if I there is another log with more specific information.

I tried removing the double quotes, but that did make a difference. I got the original implementation from here: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html

Comment: I looked, but could not find any other logs that had more detailed information about the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
Header set P3P "CP="ALL DSP COR CUR ADM TAI OUR IND COM NAV INT""
```

Should be written as:

```
Header set P3P "CP=\"ALL DSP COR CUR ADM TAI OUR IND COM NAV INT\""
```